# redirection between two domains based on regex

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

We have two domains on two different hosts (both wordpress installations):

```
oldsite.com
newsite.com
```

A lot of articles were mirrored on a new site with the same title but a different url structure:

eg:

```
oldsite.com/posts/article-about-cats
newsite.com/news/article-about-cats
```

another scenario:

```
oldsite.com/posts/article-about-cats
newsite.com/news/2018/08/09/article-about-cats
```

Assuming the title of the article is the same, what would a rewrite rule(s) be in .htaccess on the oldsite server?

Comment: If `/2018/08/09/` is dynamic part that can change for each page then you cannot have a generic rule for 2nd scenario. First one is easy to handle in a redirect rule.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I feared. It is. I guess you can't have wildcard /*/*/*/article-about-cats. What about the first one?

Comment: We can have wildcards in rules but `/2018/08/09/` is not in source URL so we cannot just generate it in target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment above that you cannot have generic rule for second scenario where target URL has dynamic part such as `/2018/08/09/`, which is not part of original URL.

For the first scenario, you can use this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?oldsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^posts/(.*)$ http://newsite.com/news/$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```